# Find Fourier Series coefficients of x=1 line function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, multinomial-coefficients

I want to know that can we find the Fourier series coefficients of the periodic signal x=1 where the limits are from -infinity to +infinity. The problem arises with the limits and it will converge to infinity. This is a past paper question and hope you guys will help to find a answer!!!

Comment: So are you saying that the period is infinity?

Comment: yes from -infinity to +infinity

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Distributions , entry 301. It is related with *Dirac delta function*. But it is F.Transform - not F.Series.

Comment: Usually, if we find Fourier Series coefficients, limits are $a,b$, where $b-a=$period ($2\pi$, $1$, other). Examples: $a=0,b=2\pi$; $a=-\pi, b=\pi$; $a=0,b=1$; ...

Comment: Hint: What is the frequency of a signal with constant value?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one term in the series that has a non-zero value, and that's the first one:

$$
x(t) = \cos(0 \cdot t) = 1
$$